# How to use FindControl

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I create dynamically buttons and I'm trying to use `FindControll` to avoid the multiple ID's, I'm assigning the ID into a Trigger of an UpdatePanel but this always says that is null, and when I press a button and make the loop to create the buttons and assign the id (Dynamically too) into the trigger. this always says that is duplicated

this is the code that I'm using:

```
protected void DynamicButton()
    {
        //BAD TOOLS INTO THE LIST AND SHOW
        List.ListUsers listsArea = new List.ListUsers();
        List<Data.Area> Area = listsArea.AreaList();

        List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposNoOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == "ENG" && x.STANDBY == 1).ToList();

        List<Button> BotonesBad = new List<Button>();

        List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == "ENG" && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

        List<Button> Botones = new List<Button>();

        var TeamGood = ListOfEquiposOk.Select(x => x.TEAM).Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (var team in TeamGood)
        {
            AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
            UpdatePanel Update = (UpdatePanel)Master.FindControl("BtnG_" + team);
            Button newButtonGood = new Button();
            Control controlGoodID = FindControl("BtnG_" + team;);
            if (controlGoodID == null && controlGoodID == null)
            {
                newButtonGood.CommandName = "Btn" + team;
                newButtonGood.Text = team;
                newButtonGood.CommandArgument = "ENG";
                newButtonGood.ID = "BtnG_" + team;

                trigger.ControlID = newButtonGood.ID;
                trigger.EventName = "Click";
                UpdatePanel4.Triggers.Add(trigger);

                newButtonGood.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);

                Good.Controls.Add(newButtonGood);

                newButtonGood.CssClass = "btn-primary outline separate";
            }
            else
            {
                Botones = Good.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
                Botones.Add(newButtonGood);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the HTML where I inster the dynamically buttons and where I'm trying to assing the id's to the `trigger`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="tools_info" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" style="width: 450px">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <h2>&nbsp Tools information</h2>
                            <br />
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#good">Good Condition</a></li>
                                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#bad">Bad Condition</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <br />
                            <div id="good" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel2">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Good">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxA1" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </asp:Panel>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: You need to ensure that you're searching the correct [naming container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @KennethK. yeah I'm sure I'm searching in the right container

Comment: First:  'UpdatePanel Update = (UpdatePanel)Master.FindControl("BtnG_" + team);' looks like its trying to find a button and convert it to an UpdatePanel, which is just never going to work.  

Second: you create 'newButtonGood' as an empty button on each loop, then if the form finds a control called BtnG_'team' it adds the empty button to Botones.

Comment: @MaCron I don't know how you says that I create a empty button, and when I make a break point and I focus on `newButtonGood ` it has a name, an ID and a text and how is the right method to find the control?

Comment: It would have those things if controlGood doesn't find a control with the generated name or if the buttons already exist on the form.

Comment: hmm so how can I fix this issue @MaCron?